# web api - asp.net identity token expires even for the subsequent request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

I am using asp.net identity for the token based authentication in web api.

For refresh token, I've implemented based on the following link

- http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

I've added the following two classes and mentioned in the start up configuration.

From the ui I've called with username and password alone through the api

**http://domain/token**

When I call the above api, the request directly goes to the method **ValidateClientAuthentication**.

But in this method the logic is, we need to send the client id and client secret.

How do we know these two before the user login for the specific user?

I thought the work flow should be like, we need to check username and password against database and should generate the access token and refresh token.

But here where do i do this logic.

What is the work flow of this system mentioned in the sample?

Before this system, I'll call the Common/login api in my application, and after successful verification,

I'll call the code to make the user as logged in

```
 var userIdentity=await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, userIdentity);
```

After the above code, I'll generate the access token from the user identity.

I've tried many times with the following implementation and fed up with the flow.

Help me regarding the logic and the flow mentioned here.

**SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider**

```
namespace AngularJSAuthentication.API.Providers
    {
        public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
        {
            public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
            {

                string clientId = string.Empty;
            string clientSecret = string.Empty;
            Client client = null;

            if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
            {
                context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
            }

            if (context.ClientId == null)
            {
                //Remove the comments from the below line context.SetError, and invalidate context 
                //if you want to force sending clientId/secrects once obtain access tokens. 
                context.Validated();
                //context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "ClientId should be sent.");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                client = _repo.FindClient(context.ClientId);
            }

            if (client == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", string.Format("Client '{0}' is not registered in the system.", context.ClientId));
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            if (client.ApplicationType == Models.ApplicationTypes.NativeConfidential)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client secret should be sent.");
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (client.Secret != Helper.GetHash(clientSecret))
                    {
                        context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client secret is invalid.");
                        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!client.Active)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client is inactive.");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin", client.AllowedOrigin);
            context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime", client.RefreshTokenLifeTime.ToString());

            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");

            if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { 
                        "as:client_id", (context.ClientId == null) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId
                    },
                    { 
                        "userName", context.UserName
                    }
                });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
            context.Validated(ticket);

        }

        public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
        {
            var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
            var currentClient = context.ClientId;

            if (originalClient != currentClient)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Refresh token is issued to a different clientId.");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            // Change auth ticket for refresh token requests
            var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);

            var newClaim = newIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "newClaim").FirstOrDefault();
            if (newClaim != null)
            {
                newIdentity.RemoveClaim(newClaim);
            }
            newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "newValue"));

            var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
            context.Validated(newTicket);

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

    }
}
```

SimpleRefreshTokenProvider

```
namespace AngularJSAuthentication.API.Providers
{
    public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
    {

        public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            var clientid = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientid))
            {
                return;
            }

            var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime"); 

                var token = new RefreshToken() 
                { 
                    Id = Helper.GetHash(refreshTokenId),
                    ClientId = clientid, 
                    Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
                    IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenLifeTime)) 
                };

                context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedUtc;
                context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresUtc;

                token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();

                var result = await _repo.AddRefreshToken(token);

                if (result)
                {
                    context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
                }

            }
        }

        public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {

            var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

            string hashedTokenId = Helper.GetHash(context.Token);

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshToken = await _repo.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);

                if (refreshToken != null )
                {
                    //Get protectedTicket from refreshToken class
                    context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
                    var result = await _repo.RemoveRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "If I set token expiration 10 mins, ..., token has expired in exact 10 mins." Well, it seems reasonable! ;-)

Comment: For the subsequent request, the token should expiration should extend. The token should expires for the idle time of 10mins..

Comment: Yes, I got it. It's just that the sentence was curios for me. BTW check my answer and the link to the tutorial to how extend the session using Refresh Tokens.

Comment: Have you tried refresh tokens as mentioned by Freerider ?

Comment: Instead of refresh tokens, there is a option like for each request reset the time. Can you give this one?

Comment: "for each request reset the time" -- there cannot be such option. With cookies, you refer to a session that is maintained on the server, so for each request the session is refreshed and will be kept alive for another (say) 10 minutes. Bearer tokens are different beasts: they contain all the necessary information in an encoded format. Including expiration time. When they expire the caller has to make sure to get new ones. This way the server can remain stateless (i.e. not maintain session state).

Answer (score 1):

How about using refresh tokens and storing them in a database, like in these two examples:

- http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/
- http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/

As broadly described in the first link, you can create your own token provider implementation to handle token refresh:

```
public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{

    public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var clientid = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientid))
        {
            return;
        }

        var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            var refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime"); 

            var token = new RefreshToken() 
            { 
                Id = Helper.GetHash(refreshTokenId),
                ClientId = clientid, 
                Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenLifeTime)) 
            };

            context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedUtc;
            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresUtc;

            token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();

            var result = await _repo.AddRefreshToken(token);

            if (result)
            {
                context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
            }

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I've added those classes and implemented. I don't know whether those methods will be called automatically or I need to call those methods. if I need to call manually, then I don't know when/where to call.

Comment: Before this method, I hardly remembering that we can reset time for subsequent request. Can we do? is that correct way to do it?

Comment: @JeevaJsb can you post a code snippet of how you've implemented your classes and how you used them? The above method (from the two links) seems valid from my pov.

Comment: Does this automatically get executed each time the user makes a request?